# How to hide top navbar and show only bottom's in mmenu

Tags: jquery, mmenu

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#my-menu").mmenu({
                  navbars: [{"position": "bottom", "content": ["<div>my       footer</div>"]        

          });
  });
```

In the above code I can enable Navbar on mmenu, However It also enables header, and i don't want to show header, So how to show only footer?

Comment: if the plugin developer hasn't enabled an option for this then the 'hack' solution would be to use the browser console to get the specific div id selector for the header element, add it to your css and make sure it's both `display: none` and probably also `height: 0px` to be sure

Answer (score 2):

I think you also need to pass in the navbar object (which is the object for the default header for the menu) with the add property set to false as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#my-menu").mmenu({
                  navbar: { add: false },
                  navbars: [{"position": "bottom", "content": ["content]   
          });
  });
</script>
```

The following page has some working examples: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/options/

Hope that helps!